# How to remove unwanted numbers on the basis of condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df,

```
                     Feb-21 Mar-21  Apr-21  May-21  Jun-21  Jul-21  Aug-21  Sep-21  Oct-21
column1 g    type                                   
CT      0      A      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN     -52480  -174544   NaN    NaN    -13163
               B      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   -43949  -8451    NaN     NaN
CT      1      A      NaN   NaN      NaN    -15265  -35577  -124986   NaN    NaN     NaN
               B      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   -79696   -675    NaN     NaN
TP1     0      A      NaN   NaN     -878    -1831   -4310     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
               B      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN      -19     -19      -19   -19     -19
```

with column1, g and column4 as index and the rest of the columns (feb-21 to Oct-21) in a dataframe

How can I compare types A and B for each column1 row-wise such that I am able to achieve the following,

1. While comparing row-wise for each type of column1, if A-th row is negative for the current column and B row is blank, then delete the negative number in the current column in type A. For instance, if we take column Jun-21 and index [CT, 0, A] we will find a negative number and its corresponding index [CT, 0, B] is NaN or blank, which implies that we remove the negative number -52480 in the final df.
2. While comparing row-wise for each type of column1, if B-th row is negative and A is blank then do nothing.
3. When both are negative, do nothing.

Final df should look like,

```
                     Feb-21 Mar-21  Apr-21  May-21  Jun-21  Jul-21  Aug-21  Sep-21  Oct-21
column1 g    type                                   
CT      0      A      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   -174544   NaN    NaN     NaN
               B      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   -43949  -8451    NaN     NaN
CT      1      A      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   -124986   NaN    NaN     NaN
               B      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   -79696   -675    NaN     NaN
TP1     0      A      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN     -4310     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
               B      NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN      -19     -19      -19   -19     -19
```

My code before it arrived at this,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('df1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_pickle('./df1.pkl')
unpickled_df = pd.read_pickle('./df1.pkl')
rem_cols = ['column2', 'column3', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7']
unpickled_df['g'] = unpickled_df.groupby(['column1', 'column4'] ).cumcount() #to keep a count of duplicates because eventually I plan on joining with the rem_cols and maintain the same amount of rows
df1 = unpickled_df.drop(rem_cols, axis=1) #dropping unnecessary columns
df1 = df1.set_index(['column1','g', 'column4'])
df1 = df1.mask(df1.ge(0)) #removed all positive numbers
```